# Merging 3 rows into 1 row in CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, csv

I have an issue with saving data in CSV.
Let's say I have data that I want to save: the name of the file, 7 coordinates in the image, and then the matrix of the image; I want them to be in 1 row of CSV file.

here's the code:

```
for each_image in raw_data:
    image_file = Image.open(each_image)
    each_file_path = image_file.filename
    print(each_file_path)
    image = cv2.imread(each_file_path)
    grey_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('imagetest', grey_image)
    cv2.setMouseCallback('imagetest', mousePoints)
    cv2.waitKey(10000)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    image_from_array = Image.fromarray(grey_image)
    width, height = image_from_array.size
    format = image_from_array.format
    mode = image_from_array.mode
    img_grey = image_from_array.convert('L')
    value = np.asarray(img_grey.getdata(), dtype=np.int).reshape
                                                ((img_grey.size[1], img_grey.size[0]))
    value = value.flatten()
    print(value)

    with open('ImageMatrix.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', escapechar=' ',
                               quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        csvwriter.writerow(circles)
        csvwriter.writerow(each_file_path)
        csvwriterMatrix = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ' ', escapechar = ' ',
                                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE )
        csvwriterMatrix.writerow(value)
```

The output is correct but they are in 3 different rows.
My question is: How can I merge 3 rows into 1 for each data?

Comment: You need to write all the data for a row via a single call to the `writerow()` method of the *one* `csv.writer` for the output file. That means you'll have to create a list holding all the values representing each of the different things you say you want on each one so you can pass it as an argument when you make the call.

Comment: What does the current output look like? What do you plan to modify that file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write all the data for a row via a single call to the `writerow()` method of the one `csv.writer` for the output file.

That means you'll have to create a list holding all the values representing each of the different things you say you want on each one so you can pass it as an argument when you make the call. – martineau